# validate dynamically generated variable in using javascript

Tags: javascript

**I have a scenario where i need to check whether a variable is not null using java script**

Now these variables can be generated automatically and their naming convention is going to be like below

```
**Attribute.1.Name='aaa'
Attribute.2.Name='aaa'
Attribute.3.Name=''**
```

and so on.

how do i validate something like this where i do not now the exact variable name. **All i know is the pattern of the variable.**

Code example

```
FunctionName({'Attribute.1.Name':'test','Attribute.2.Name':'test2'});
```

Thanks

Comment: How are those variables generated? In which scope are they stored?

Comment: so the user will write them while calling one of my api's, so basically this way user can pass multiple values for one property

Comment: Code example please. How is the user calling your API?

Answer (score 1):

```
var FunctionName = function(parameters) {
    if (parameters['Attribute.1.Name'] == null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and if you wanted to loop through all properties of the object:

```
var FunctionName = function(parameters) {
    for (var name in parameters) {
        if (parameters.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            if (parameters[name] == null) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Darin-- these parameters are dynamic and user can enter any number of them. so hard coding won't work

Comment: @Amit, then you could loop through them as shown in my second example.